# How to order HTML when converting to paragraph stacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#knop").click(function () {

        var pizzas = ["Margherita", "Napolitana", "Salami", "Prosciutto", "Funghi", "Tonno"];
        var Prijs = ["6.00", "7.20", "7.50", "7.50", "7.00", "8.00"];

        if ($('input[name="M"]').is(":checked")) {
            $("#Pizza").html(pizzas[0]);
            $("#prijs").html(Prijs[0]);
        };
        if ($('input[name="N"]').is(":checked")) {
            $("#Pizza").html(pizzas[1]);
            $("#prijs").html(Prijs[1]);
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Pizzas container" id="checkbox_pizza">
    <h1>Kies uw Pizza.</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="M" id="g" value="0"> &euro;6,00 -Margherita (Kaas en tomaten)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="N" id="h" value="1"> &euro;7,20 -Napolitana (tomaten, kaas, kappertjes, ansjovis)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="S" id="i" value=2""> &euro;7,50 -Salami (kaas, tomaten en salami)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="P" id="j" value="3"> &euro;7,50 -Prosciutto (tomaten, kaas, ham)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="F" id="k" value="4"> &euro;7,00 -Funghi (tomaten, kaas, champions)
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="T" id="l" value="5"> &euro;8,00 -Tonno (tomaten, kaas, tonijn, ui)
        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="knop" value="knop"/>
        <p id="Pizza"></p><p id="prijs"></p>

    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my html and jquery code. Now my problem is that when I have checked the first and second checkboxes and click the #knop button, I only see the second checkbox results in my `<p>`.

Now I know this is because of the second part of my function, but how do I get it so that both the result will show?

Comment: are you trying to display both first and second result or all ..what ever checked?

Comment: something like this in http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zBoWwv

Comment: You forgot to add the **quantity** input. What if I want 2 Margheritas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display both checked items ,use below option
codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zBoWwv

```
    if ($('input[name="N"]').is(":checked")) {
        $("#Pizza").html(pizzas[1]);
        $("#prijs").html(Prijs[1]);
    };
    if ($('input[name="M"]').is(":checked")) {
        $("#Pizza").prepend('<p>'+pizzas[0]+'</p>');
        $("#prijs").prepend('<p>'+Prijs[0]+'</p>');
    };
```

Using .html() is overwriting the first html content

You can use append() to append whatever checked ,use

```
        if ($('input[name="M"]').is(":checked")) {
            $("#Pizza").html(pizzas[0]);
            $("#prijs").html(Prijs[0]);
        };

            if ($('input[name="N"]').is(":checked")) {
            $("#Pizza").append(pizzas[1]);
            $("#prijs").append(Prijs[1]);
        };
```

Codepen for append - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ezBMeN

Comment: If you looking to extend for all checkboxes,append is the best option...For the first two checkboxes as mentioned in post, then use prepend for first element pizzas and Prijs to the second...Hope this works for you :)